# Old modifications appears when importing my site template

Tags: 2010, list, site-template, export, import

*Environment : SharePoint 2010 Foundation*

Actually I want to import my site from a site collection (named SC1) to another one (named SC2).

**What I do :**

- Export my site as a template
- Download the template from SC1
- Upload and Activate the template on SC2

But some weird things happened.

My site has a custom CSS -> works well.

All the lists are here but I noticed that a field in a list had his old name. I modified this name about 2 months ago !

Also, the "default.aspx" page is weird too. I just have 2 pictures (in webparts as well). They appear well BUT I have 3-4 webparts which are created by themselves. I think those webparts are associated to the real default.aspx page when you create a new site.

Also again, my groups are quite simply lost.

For those reasons, my site doesn't work well.

Do you have any idea ?